# Filenet search is not respecting the 'Deny View Content' access right

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I did a bulk security update on all the documents for a certain clause, to deny "**View Content**" permission. Even though for each document I can see that the security change is updated, I am still able to search the documents and view its properties which is a security issue for us. Please let me know if there are other changes that needs to be done.

Through the java API when I try to fetch the `getAccessAllowed` for the document, I can see that it does not have "**View Content**" rights.

As per the attached link, This is by design.

If the #AUTHENTICATED_USERS group is present at the object store level and **Set Owner of any object** or even if just **connect** and **Create** are **allowed**, Then the user can search documents and view all its properties regardless of the document or class definition level permissions.

Is there any way to override this constraint?

Comment: How did you update the security? API or script wizard? Also did you try removing #AUTHENTICATED_USERS?